# Access the label formatter of an integrated chart of AG Grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I want to limit the length of the labels in an AG integrated Chart. I would use the formatter for the labels of the axes but do not know how to access the label-formatter of an integrated chart created by my application.

Creation of an application created integrated chart in my application:

```
const chartContainer = document.querySelector('#myChart') as HTMLElement;
const params: CreatePivotChartParams = {
      chartType: 'groupedColumn',
      chartContainer: chartContainer,
      chartThemeName: 'ag-vivid',
      chartThemeOverrides: {
        common: {
          legend: {
            enabled: true,
            position: 'bottom',
          },
          navigator: {
            enabled: true,
            height: 10,
          },
        },
      },
    };
 ref = this.gridApi.createPivotChart(params);
```

html:

```
<div class="chart" id="myChart"></div>
```

I looked through the documentation of AG Grid and saw that it is possible to declare a label formatter for a standalone chart but could not find anything for the integrated charts.

Answer (score 0):

After a little mor digging I found this solution:

```
    const chartContainer = document.querySelector('#myChart') as HTMLElement;
    const params: CreatePivotChartParams = {
      chartType: 'groupedColumn',
      chartContainer: chartContainer,
      chartThemeName: 'ag-vivid',
      chartThemeOverrides: {
        common: {
          legend: {
            enabled: true,
            position: 'bottom',
          },
          navigator: {
            enabled: true,
            height: 10,
          },
          axes: {
            groupedCategory: {
              label: {
                formatter: (params: any) => {
                  if (params.value.length > 22) {
                    return params.value.substr(0, 20) + '...';
                  }

                  return params.value;
                },
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    };

    ref = this.gridApi.createPivotChart(params);
```